# How to define zero function?

Tags: matlab

I have defined a function `TEST=@(t)t.^2` in my program. However, in some situation, the `TEST` is needed to be set to be a zero function. I write `TEST2=@(t)0.*TEST`. Unfortunately, error occurs when I compute TEST2(1):
`Undefined operator '.*' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.`
I would like to know any way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error says it all. `TEST` is a function handle, and multiplying a function handle by 0 is not defined. in order to convert the `TEST` function handle in `TEST2` definition into a numeric data just use it as a function and define its input:

```
TEST2=@(t)0.*TEST(t)
```

Comment: or just `TEST2=@(t)0`? :)

Comment: @Wolfie that won't work well for vector inputs (which by the `.*` in the question I assume is possible). you're right that it's possible to do `TEST2=@(t) zeros(size(t))`.

Comment: Ah yes I was being hasty, didn't consider vectors (somehow!), the `zeros` option would be much quicker if the function `TEST` takes much time to run, but assumes the returned value is the same size as `t`. Your original answer is the safest option!